# Joomla unified logins for forum and a custom made php sub-site

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

I'm building a site with Joomla where a forum should exist amongst other things. But also I plan to develop a custom made functionality (diary-like) with a php inserts (it really works, for example with jumi). The problem is that I suppose nobody will understand if the forum and this sub-site will have separated logins. I'd use an existing forum authentication for my code also, but I don't like the idea that the login will look like forum-only login. I see there are bridges exist (like JFusion), but should I choose one particular forum extension if I plan to use a particular bridge extension? And are bridges easy to access with custom-made php code?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a Joomla 1.5 website, you will want to create a `user` plugin that will log the user into your custom site as they log into Joomla. Take a look at `plugins/user/example.php` for an example `user` plugin. The `onLoginUser` function will be called just after someone successfully logs into Joomla. At this point, you'll have all of their data in the `$user` array that's passed into the function. You should be able to use this information to create a bridge into your external PHP application.

Comment: The existing forum extensions *should* be using this login information, yes.